# Unknown Column id in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me I've got 2 MySQL queries that get unknown column id when I try to run them. I might add that I am converting this database from SQLServer 2005 to MySQL and they run fine in SQL Server 2005.

Here's 1 of them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.id AS `genre`  
    FROM media_playlist_sequence MPS  
    INNER JOIN media               M   ON M.`key`           = MPS.media_key 
    INNER JOIN media_playlists     MP  ON MP.`key`          = MPS.playlist_key 
    INNER JOIN node_media_playlist NMP ON NMP.playlist_key  = MP.`key` 
    INNER JOIN nodes               N   ON N.`key`           = NMP.node_key 
    INNER JOIN media_files         MF  ON MF.media_key      = M.`key` 
    INNER JOIN media_locations     ML  ON ML.media_file_key = MF.media_file_key  
        AND ML.node_key = n.`key`  
    INNER JOIN media_genres        MG  ON MG.media_key      = M.`key` 
    INNER JOIN genres              G   ON G.`key`           = MG.genre_key 
WHERE M.is_ready = 1    
    AND MP.id = 'Channels'    
    AND N.id = 'VIC-WIN7' 
    AND mf.is_quad_image = 0
```

Comment: Does the `id` column exist on the three relevant tables in your query (`media_playlists`, `genres`, `nodes`)?

Comment: There is no `id` column as it's saying it.

Comment: The id column does exist in in media_playlists, genres and nodes which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Long shot, but have you tried using upper case `G` `... DISTINCT G.id ... `?

Comment: The Long shot worked njk - case sensitivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's a case sensitivity issue.  MySQL can be case sensitive by default whereas SQL Server is not.

Comment: +1 because it's a good idea, but [This depends on the OS that MySql is running on...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: all of the id columns are lower case

Comment: Per njk as well, fix your aliases too, just to be sure.

Comment: You're right John - I tried switching g to G as suggested by njk and it worked.